# How do I get the ID of the selected cell in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to get the ID of the cell that is focused inside a selected row?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using inline editing. and using context menu for the grid.

I want to be able to show the context menu only for specific cells inside the row.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean? The cell can have focus only of it is in the editing mode. Which editing mode you use (form editing, inline editing, cell editing)? What information you know about the cell having the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can use [onRightClickRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event handler. You will have information about the rowid and you can use context menu using the information.

**UPDATED:** If you use `jquery.contextmenu.js` from http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/, which you can find in the `plugins` subdirectory of the last 4.0 version of jqGrid you can bind all jqGrid rows with data with `$("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu(...)` to context menu. Inside of `onContextMenu: function(e) {/*here*/}` handler you can get row id within the `onContextMenu` function:

```
var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
```

Comment: Is there another way ? because i'm not initalizing the context menu from the row right click event. so if i add the "onRightClickRow" my "onShowMenu:" function will not recognize the row id i got from the onRightClickRow... thank's.

Comment: Thank's! this is what I'm using, I want to get the "td" id - the cell id. I used $(e_.target).attr("id") and it returned the cells id.

Comment: @user590586: You are welcome! Are you sure that `$(e_.target).attr("id")` return not empty string in your case? In the most cases `<td>` elements has no id. Only all rows has ids. Why you need the id of td element? If you need address the `<td>` element you can directly use `$(e_.target)`. If needed you can save the value in a variable and use it instead of `id` of `<td>`.